# expect methods reads a wrong value of wrapper.vm.shown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, karma-runner, avoriaz

I'm testing my [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) component and a very strange issue occurred.

**Here is my test**

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';


let wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { globals: {$route},});

it('the click changes the value of shown', () => {
    // This passes
    expect(wrapper.vm.shown).to.equal(false);

    // the click on this element will turn shown value into true
    wrapper.first('#my_link').trigger('click');

    // the value of shown is indeed true now
    console.log(wrapper.vm.shown); // LOG LOG: true

    expect(wrapper.vm.shown).to.equal(true); // expected undefined to equal true
});
```

What's happening and why `shown` is `undefined` when passed as argument to `expect` method and is boolean when displayed through `console.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM hasn't finished updating when you call the `expect` the second time.

Use [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to wait for the DOM to be updated before calling `expect`:

```
wrapper.first('#my_link').trigger('click');

wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
  expect(wrapper.vm.shown).to.equal(true);
});
```

---

When working with asynchronous code, `console.log` will sometimes log values lazily, meaning they won't be the value you'd expect at the moment of that line's execution. [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

Comment: That's nice!!! thx, [$nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)